# Why is one switch dependent on the other switch position in my double light switch?

Tags: electrical, switch

I just a installed a new outlet and powered it from an existing light switch. I replaced the single switch with a double switch.

Wiring: hot to black (common) double switch terminal. Black wire from light to one brass terminal. Black wire from outlet to other brass terminal. Neutrals connected. Grounds connected, then connected to green terminal on double light switch.

When breaker is restored, the light switch operates normally. The outlet is only powered when both the light switch is on and the outlet switch is on.

Why are both switches not independent?

[image: 1]

Comment: I can't follow your wiring description, but you connected the new switch to the wrong side of the old switch.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the double switch wiring?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to insert or paste a picture. First time user . . . Hang on.

Comment: Since your new and have a 1 rep, just upload it to imgur.com and put a link here in comments, someone with more rep can edit your question.

Comment: http://imgur.com/rQQIHCK

Comment: What model is the double switch?

Comment: It's a Cooper combination decorator two single pole switches 7728W-BOX

Comment: Disconnect the new switch, buzz out the connections with an ohmmeter (or look at the instruction diagram that it oughtta have come with), and the solution should be clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you have mixed up the light-hot and the panel-hot wires. So when you flip the first switch it supplies power to the (whole) switch. You need to move the light wire (yellow in the picture below) and put it on the brass screw corresponding to the one you thought was the light wire. The wire that you thought went to the light is the power/panel hot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I did. You are awesome, Ben - thanks!